# Expandable Tableview work with sectionHeader

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to load my different controller using Expandable Tableview but my headerview is set 
as switch condition

For Header XXX1 -> two sub menu a and b .. 
For Header XXX2-> sub menu c
but for Header XXX3 no sub menu ,, So i will work on click with XXX3(currently working with check SectionData.count == 0 ) but for multiple how to manage  .. check out my code

```
 sectionNames = ["xxxx1","xxxx2","xxx3","xxxx4"] //this is main header
 sectionItems = [ ["a","b"],[c],[],[],[],[],[],[]]// This is sub menu items

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if (self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber == section) {
            let arrayOfItems = self.sectionItems[section] as! NSArray
            return arrayOfItems.count;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
        //return arraylist.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if (self.sectionNames.count != 0) {
            return self.sectionNames[section] as? String
        }
        return ""
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
        return footerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.5

    } 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifer, for: indexPath)
        let section = self.sectionItems[indexPath.section] as! NSArray
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.text = section[indexPath.row] as? String
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

        }


        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        //  print(indexPath as Any)

        //getting the current cell from the index path
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell
        //   print(currentCell as Any)

        //getting the text of that cell
        let currentItem = currentCell.textLabel!.text
        print(currentItem!)

        switch currentItem { 
          case "XXXX1":
            //// Here unable to do any work
            break
          case "a":
            APICalla()
          case "b":
            APICallb ()
          default:
            break
        }
        return
    }
```

[Using this link](https://vasundharavision.com/blog/ios/expandable-tableview-without-third-party)

Comment: didnt understand. please make it more clear.. do you want to know how you can manage didSelectRowAt for different sections and rows?

Comment: here you can see i  will managing  sectionItems at ( cellForRowAt) but how to  manage  sectionNames to my switch condition at (didSelectRowAt)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this tutorial is quite poor.

Swift is an object oriented language so use a custom model, a generic `Section` object with `name`, `items` and the information if the section is collapsed

```
class Section<T> {
    var name : String
    var items = [T]()

    var isCollapsed = false

    init(name : String, items : [T] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

and a suitable struct for the items with a title and a closure to be called in `didSelect`

```
struct Item {
    let title : String
    let selectorClosure : (() -> Void)?
}
```

Rather than using multiple arrays populate the data source array consistently

```
var sections = [Section<Item>(name:"xxxx1", items: [Item(title: "a", selectorClosure: APICalla), Item(title: "b", selectorClosure: APICallb)]),
                Section<Item>(name:"xxxx2", items: [Item(title: "c", selectorClosure: APICallc)]),
                Section<Item>(name:"xxxx3")]
```

---

In `numberOfRowsInSection` return the proper number of items depending on `isCollapsed`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let currentSection = sections[section]
    return (currentSection.isCollapsed) ? 0 : currentSection.items.count
}
```

---

In `cellForRow` don't use *typeless* Foundation collection types

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifer, for: indexPath)
    let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    return cell
}
```

---

In the method to collapse/expand the sections just toggle `isCollapsed`

```
let currentSection = sections[section]
currentSection.isCollapsed.toggle()
```

and perform the animation

---

`titleForHeaderInSection` is much simpler, too

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
   return sections[section].name
}
```

---

In `didSelectRow` **never** get any data from the ***view*** (the cell) get it from the ***model*** (the data source array) and call the selector closure. With this logic a switch is not needed.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    item.selectorClosure?()
}
```

Comment: '(ViewController) -> () -> ()' is not convertible to '(() -> Void)?'...  at    ``` var sections = [Section<Item>(name:"xxxx1", items: [Item(title: "a", selectorClosure: APICalla), Item(title: "b", selectorClosure: APICallb)]), ```

Comment: Where and how is `APICalla` declared? And `sections` must be declared inside the view controller.

Comment: its nothing a basic function() for call    like func APICallc()
    {

        alert("test")
    }

Comment: and sections are declared within the viewcontroller

Comment: Then the code is supposed to work. I tested it. The methods must be declared in the same view controller, too.

Comment: when i put this Var sections items with in ViewdidLoad() .. they call APICalla ,APICallb easily  ..but out side dnt work .. and we have to take this as public variable because numberOfRowsInSection, titleForHeaderInSection using this values

Comment: `sections` must be declared on the top level of the class like your multiple arrays. Check the scopes (`{ ... }`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204881/discussion-between-santosh-and-vadian).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift4** I think this will helps you

```
// declare globally
   var isExpanded : Bool = true
   var indexOfSection = Int()
   var yourArray = [ModelName]()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        indexOfSection = 999
    }
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            if yourArray.count > 0{
                return yourArray.count
            }else{
                return 0

        }

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x,y: 0 , width: view.frame.size.width ,height: 60))
        headerView.backgroundColor = .white
        let collapseBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: headerView.frame.origin.x,y: headerView.frame.origin.y , width: view.frame.size.width ,height: 60))
        collapseBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandSection(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        collapseBtn.tag = section
        collapseBtn.backgroundColor = .clear
        headerView.addSubview(collapseBtn)

        return headerView
    }

    @objc func expandSection(sender:UIButton){
        print(sender.tag)
        if isExpanded == true{
            indexOfSection = sender.tag
            mIdeaTableView.reloadData()
            isExpanded = false
            mTableView.reloadSections([indexOfSection], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.bottom)
        }else{
            indexOfSection = 999
            isExpanded = true
            self.mTableView.reloadData()

        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 60

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            if yourArray.count > 0{
                if yourArray[section].items!.count > 0{
                    if indexOfSection == section{
                        return yourArray[section].items!.count
                    }else{
                        return 0
                    }
                }else{
                    return 0
                }
            }else{
                return 0
            }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “CellID”, for: indexPath) as! Cell
            if yourArray[indexPath.section]. items!.count > 0{
                if yourArray[indexPath.section]. items!.count > 0{
                    let ideas = yourArray[indexPath.section].ideaItems
                    if ideas!.count > 0{
                        if indexOfSection == indexPath.section{
                            cell.mLbl.text = ideas![indexPath.row].name ?? ""
                            if ideas![indexPath.row].isExpanded == true{
                                cell.mAddImg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tick")
                            }else{
                                cell.mAddImg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "edit213-1")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

            return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
                return 60
    }
 }

//Structure of my response 
{
            items =             (
                                {
                    name = “a”;
                },
                                {
                    name = “b”;
                },
                                      );
            name = “xxxx1”;
        }
            items =             (
                                {
                    name = “c”;
                },
                                      );
            name = “xxxx2”;
        }

}
```